# How can I transfer the raw data from `/dev/graphics/fb0` to a picture using a python script?

Tags: android, python, framebuffer

Following [this](http://my.opera.com/otaku_2r/blog/grab-a-frame-in-android-frame-buffer):

```
$ adb shell
# cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /sdcard/frame.raw
# exit
```

- How can I transfer the raw data from `/dev/graphics/fb0` to a picture
  using a python script?
- what each byte is represent in the raw data output? is it RGB values for each pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

were you looking for something like http://code.google.com/p/android-fb2png/ ?